# Replacing value of 2 or more variables(column) with another variable condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJNrn.png)Basically, Im trying to give the team in the snitchCatcher variable + 5 goals in their specific homeGoals/awayGoals variable.
`

```
ifelse(Df$snitchCatcher == "home", 
       Df$homeGoals + 5, 
       Df$awayGoals + 5)
```

`

This is the code that i use, it does give correct calculation in the console, but yet it is defined at 1 list and not yet make any change inside of the dataframe variable. Is there any chance i can directly change/replace the value of the variable with above condition?

I am very new to R, i have think about subsetting data, create a data with only 1 team then combine later, etc,... however i do not know what to do, and I have already late on my assignment. I really need some help to at least solve the above issue so I can continue. Please help.

I will post a screencap of the dataframe

Comment: Hi there and welcome! To recieve better help faster, please edit your question to include the sample data in code form (ie, `dput(your_data)`) and not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Df$homeGoals <-  ifelse(Df$snitchCatcher == "home", 
       Df$homeGoals + 5, 
       Df$homeGoals )

Df$awayGoals <-  ifelse(Df$snitchCatcher != "home", 
       Df$awayGoals + 5, 
       Df$awayGoals )
```

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse/dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(homeGoals = if_else(snitchCatcher == "home", homeGoals+5, homeGoals+0)) %>%
    mutate(awayGoals = if_else(snitchCatcher == "away", awayGoals+5, awayGoals+0))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I definitely gonna try this right now!